# CSS of my site broken in chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

Having a really hard time figuring this out.

http://www.gemcode.co.uk/

The site works fine on firefox but is completely broken on chrome.

Havent tested IE as of yet.

I recently bought a basic level membership of cloudflare but I have turned on development mode and purged cache from wordpress CMS panel and the cloudflare settings. This is the most recent change I have made. Before this it was working perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am clueless.

[image: chrome view]

[image: Firefox view]

** Added this into the style.css **

.page-container {
padding-top: 0px;!important
}

It comes up fine on my browser now?
how about you guys?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Attach a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Agree, works fine in my chrome. "Totally broken" is not an explanation of the issue. You must include the related code, the explanation of the problem, and the desired behaviour

Comment: I guess the OP is refering to the fact that the page appears empty when the scrollbar is at its top position.

Comment: @CherryDT... I'm not getting that same "symptom" on my browser :/

Comment: I have added screenshots, hopefully this helps.

Comment: I have Chrome 50.0.2661.87 on Windows 10 and I do have the problem. I guess that the issue is not introduced by any change the OP did then, but by a browser update...? @RohanBüchner What version do you have?

Comment: I guess you have a plugin that creates conflicts. It is calculating wrong, because it injects a `padding-top: 1023px` in the `#page-container`

Comment: Same thing happens of mobile, after you click a link on mobile it goes back to what it should look like. Again, I am using chrome on mobile. Not sure if that info helps...

Comment: Actually, interestingly enough, it happens for me not every time. I now tested loading the page 10 times and it happened 4 times. So there is probably also some kind of race condition there. So in theory, it *could* still be that the CloudFlare thing triggered the error because it changed loading times. Still, the error was probably always there, just not visibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something gone wrong with your JS as I can reproduce the issue on my Chrome - (Canary Version 52).

I think you need to roll back to your previous iteration and then have a look at what changed from when it was working fine to now.

In my experience with WP using page builders, the JS calculations for margin and padding can break very easily. Which seems to be exactly whats gone wrong with your site:

```
class="et-animated-content"
```

Is the main culprit.

Most often these issues come from a minification process gone wrong.

Also, you should investigate how your JS/CSS files are served given there is about 2 second delay before any styling what so ever kicks in, which is far too much.